# No language option after installing Polylang for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

I have installed Polylang in accordance with the installation guide in https://polylang.pro/doc/installation. After I activate the plugin, I don not get the "languages" option as one should (ref: https://polylang.pro/doc/create-languages/) . There are no error messages during or after the installation that indicates that something went wrong during the installation.

I have tried to reinstall it, without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood the install guide, I needed to install the basic Polylang before it worked. I somehow read that it could not be installed at the same time.